# Google spreadsheet error not sending file when getting file by Name

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Here is my code for the following, if I change the function getFilesByName() to getFileById() then it works perfectly fine, what is different and why is this not working as it should?

[image: Google Script Error]

```
// This constant is written in column C for rows for which an email
// has been sent successfully.
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function sendEmails2() {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 2;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 4;   // Number of rows to process

  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 5)

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var name = row[0];
    var emailAddress = row[1];  // First column
    var filename = DriveApp.getFilesByName(row[2]); // Second column
    var message = row[3];     // Third column
    var emailSent = row[4];  // Fourth column

    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT) {  // Prevents sending duplicates
      var subject = "TEST" + name;
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message, {
          name: 'TEST',
          attachments: [filename.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
      });
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 5).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is actually pretty explanatory, you have a `File Iterator` class ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)) and not a `File`, you must apply the method `next()` to get the most recently updated file with that name, if you have more files with that name, you can use a combination o `hasNext()` and `next()` in a loop.

Comment: Okay using .next() worked just fine :) Sorry I am a bit new to google script but from my understanding if you do not specify .next() after getFileByName because names can be duplicates and id's can not, am I right?

Comment: That's right, you can see the return type in the [DriveApp documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app), getFileById returns a file, while getFilesByName returns a FileIterator, keep the documentation side by side while coding so you know what methods you have avaible and what's the return type.

Comment: Will do, Thanks mate, appreciate it.